# how to exit an if statement without effecting the rest of php when if returns false

Tags: php, mysql, sql

//This has been driving me nuts lol.. code to execute below. i am trying to exit the script if one if statement is true, and continue if it is false

```
<?php

require('includes/config.php');

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "database";

$selectQuery = "SELECT username, email, tokens, tokenstatus, tokensinc, tokenstatus1, tokenswith, tokenstatus2 FROM members WHERE username = '".($_SESSION['username']) ."'";

$updateQuery = "UPDATE members SET tokens=tokens - 10, tokenstatus='(Pending Tokens)' ,tokenswith=tokenswith + 10, tokenstatus1='(Pending Tokens)' WHERE username = '".($_SESSION['username']) ."'";

// Create connection
$db = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$db) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//if not logged in redirect to login page
if(!$user->is_logged_in()) { header('Location: login.php'); exit(); }

//define page title
$title = 'Withdraw ~ Pixel Jag';

//include header template
require('layout/header.php');
?>
<div class="container">
<div class="panel panel-default">
<?php


$result = mysqli_query($db, $selectQuery);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
echo "<ul class='list-group'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

//the if statement below is the code to execute, if this returns true i want it to exit  script, if its false i want it to continue to update//

```
  if ($row['tokens'] < 10) {
        echo "<li class='list-group-item list-group-item-danger'>You do not have enough tokens!</li>";
    }
}
echo "</ul>";

}
```

//see below for code i wish to execute instead if the above is returned false//

```
if (mysqli_query($db, $updateQuery)) {
echo "<ul class='list-group'><li class='list-group-item list-group-item-success'><h4>Record updated successfully!</h4></li></ul>";
} else {
echo "Error updating record: " . mysqli_error($db);
}

mysqli_close($db);
?>

<div class="panel-footer">
<a href="index.php"><h4>Back To Dashboard..</h4></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<?php
//include header template
require('layout/footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: You don't actually want to stop the PHP script, you want to continue but skip the `update`, right? If so put the `update` bit in an `else` block. Otherwise the answer to the actual question would be `exit` or `die`. You also should parameterize your query and use prepared statements.

Comment: [PHP continue](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php)

Comment: thanks, yes thats exactly what i mean.. so i should add else { if (mysqli_query($db, $updateQuery)) {
    echo "<ul class='list-group'><li class='list-group-item list-group-item-success'><h4>Record updated successfully!</h4></li></ul>";
} else {
    echo "Error " . mysqli_error($db);
}}

Comment: Yes, that should be it.

Answer (score 0):

please just put a flag $isValid with the default value is true

```
$isValid = true;

while(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0 || $isValid) {
     if ($row['tokens'] < 10) {
       echo "<li class='list-group-item list-group-item-danger'>You do not have  enough tokens!</li>";
         $isValid = false;
     }
}
```

alright if the flag is true do the update

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be, in my opinion, if you are within a function or method, using a return; statement.

```
function some(){
  if(true){
  return;
  }
  else{
  //do other stuff

  if(true){
  return;
  }

}

}
```

But there are also a lot of ways in php to interrupt execution. You are indeed using some of those.

```
die;
exit;
throw new Exception('some error');//we need an exception handler in this case
```

then:

```
if ($row['tokens'] < 10) {
        echo "<li class='list-group-item list-group-item-danger'>You do not have enough tokens!</li>";
die;// or exit or return if you are within a function o method
    }
```